# How can I verify git clone is working correctly?

Tags: linux, git, bash, server

I'm following the [documentation provided here by git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server) to setup a bare git repository in a folder called `root`.

I started in the root directory where I ran

```
git init
git -A *
git commit -m "test"
```

I then ran `git status` and all appears good.

Next I ran the line from the documentation at a directory one level above the repo I created above.

```
git clone --bare root root.git
```

This created `root.git` but I cannot see any evidence that anything was cloned I just see a set of files and directories when I `cd root.git`.

I don't know how to verify it was actually cloned, and if it was why can't I see the original files?

[image]

Comment: Clearly it doesn't "do nothing" since it did create a directory called `root.git/` containing some files. In the future, please try to be more precise with your questions and titles.

Comment: This is a well formatted question that provides research, links and a pretty picture.

Comment: You can't see the actual files because of the magic of git ^_^ 
when you do the `--bare` flag - it tells git to just be a git - and not a workspace - 
I highly recommend you let git's magic stay that way - and be magic - but if you want to dissect it - the files are under `objects`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `--bare` --- you are telling git to clone *just* the git portion -

This is the option you use when you want to have a remote repository that does not include a workspace.

If you want to verify that it actually cloned your changes, you'll want to clone it again in a different directory - *without* the `--bare` flag

I would recommend using the full path to do this:

```
cd /path/to/some/workspace
git clone /path/to/your/root.git successful-git-clone #that last bit is optional
```

This will put the workspace contents of `root.git` into a folder named `successful-git-clone/` - without that last bit, it will default to `root/` -

Comment: There you go - that will allow you to verify that your `--bare` clone worked as expected...

Comment: You cloned the repository. You just didn't check out a working copy from any branch.

Comment: that documentation is half-dumb, then... 
If you can scp to a remote server, then you should...
log into the remote server over ssh - go to the directory you want to keep your git repos - `git init --bare repo-name` - and then, on your local machine: `git clone user@remote-server:/path/to/repo` - THAT WAY - your local repo knows where the remote repo is - and you can `git push` and `git pull` without having to manually `git remote add`

Comment: @rm - but still you only have to `git remote add` one time correct?

Comment: right - unless you want to have multiple remotes, which can sometimes be the case. Also, in that case, you have to run some odd `git push --set-upstream origin master` so that you can run `git push` instead of `git push origin master` - - - `origin` being the name of the remote - and `master` being the branch - -

Comment: But you see, if you go on - it doesn't recommend you do that - it recommends cloning it again - which is kinda funny that the cannonical docs tell you to do it in such a round-about way... oh well!

Answer (score 2):

Even if you are in a `bare` repository, some git commands works and you could do a `git branch` to see if you have all your branches or `git log` to look at your commits...